# When Stack Exchange Data is updated

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

I've read [FAQ](https://data.stackexchange.com/faq) and it says:

> **How frequently is Stack Exchange Data
> Explorer updated?**
>
> Data is updated monthly.

But its already March and I can't see February's data.

So when exactly is data updated?

Comment: See also answers to similar question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134589/on-what-day-of-the-month-is-stack-exchange-data-explorer-updated/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updates usually occur around the 9th or 10th of each month.

Comment: I wish there was a list of these times... or, is there one?